# ui-select multiple: ng-model how will it be saved as string and not as array

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I have this ui select:

```
<ui-select multiple
    ng-model="meas.daysSelected"
    theme="bootstrap"
    close-on-select="false">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="days">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="day in days | filter:$select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="day | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>

$scop.days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue' ... ]
```

it is in a simple table with angular ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="meas in foo= (res.foos | filter: subSearch : strict)">
```

and I filter it with:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="subSearch.daysSelected">
```

The problem is like this: the "daySelected" model is becoming an array when I select an object and then de-select it. the filter of angular just dismisses it and filters it.
So I need help in one of the 2:

1. make daySelected as a string (when selected it will be: "sun, mon"
   or
2. adjust the filter to work in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the search text is going to be like "Mon,Tue" which will filter all the ui-selects which have ["Mon","Tue"] you can write your own filter function and pass that.  For example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="meas in foo= (res.foos | filter: $ctrl.filterDaysSelected">
```

And in your controller you'd need to create that function:

```
$ctrl.filterDaysSelected = function(value, index, array) {}
```

Where you would need to:

- Split the value of your search criteria by ","
- Validate that each item in your split array exists in the function value parameter